# Unable to Switch to Iframe using Appium in real iPhone Safari Browser

Tags: appium

I am writing a test for typical ecommerce application where the billing section is in IFrame. Webdriver couldn't able to identify the objects inside Iframe

driver.switchTo().frame("frameid");

Device - Real device(iPhone 5C)
IOS - 7.1
Browser - Safari

refer the below link for details
https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-switch-to-iframe-using-appium-1-3-2-beta/1683

Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue.